# How to break out of switch case from inside a function defined inside the switch case in golang?

Tags: go, switch-statement, goquery

The question sounds weird but I didn't know any better way to put it. I am using goquery and I am inside a `switch-case`:

```
switch{
    case url == url1:
        doc.Find("xyz").Each(func(i int,s *goquery.Selection){
            a,_ := s.Attr("href")
            if a== b{
                //I want to break out of the switch case right now. I dont want to iterate through all the selections. This is the value.
                break
            }
        })
}
```

Using `break` gives the following error:
`break is not in a loop`

What should I use here to break out of the switch-case instead of letting the program iterate over each of the selections and run my function over each of them?

Comment: goto is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of goquery's [`EachWithBreak`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.EachWithBreak) method to stop iterating over the selection:

```
switch {
    case url == url1:
        doc.Find("xyz").EachWithBreak(func(i int,s *goquery.Selection) bool {
            a,_ := s.Attr("href")
            return a != b
        })
}
```

As long as there's no remaining code in your switch case, you do not need to use a `break`.